# mem-fs-editor: How to copy relative symlinks?

Tags: node.js, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I've got a directory which contains a lot of files and one (or more) `symlinkname -> .` symlink. I want to copy the contents of the entire directory to a new location. the following code copies everything just fine, though it skips the symlink. Adding `globOptions.follow = true` only makes it loop indefinitely, which makes sense since it will try to dereference it. How can I just make it copy all the content + symlinks without trying to follow them?

```
this.fs.copy(
  this.destinationPath() + '/**',
  this.destinationPath('build/html'),
  {
    globOptions: {
      follow: true // This will make the copy loop infinitely, which makes sense. 
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: You cannot publish symlinks to npm, not sure how that would ever work.

Comment: Without knowing a lot about possible implications, it sounds like it should be so straight forward, just copy a link to a specific location? Edit: It's not my intention to publish anything to npm btw, I simply use Yeoman generator to scaffold my project which contains symlinks.

Comment: We might be able to follow the symlink and consider it as a folder, but I don't really see how we could copy the symlink itself (or how that could be used). A lot of what we're trying to do with Yeoman is prevent bad UX, and any special handling of symlink would open a jar of worms. - Feel free to open an issue on mem-fs-editor; I'm happy to discuss it further in an appropriate channel. For now, symlinks are not supported so there's probably no way to get it to work (apart from `follow: true`)

Answer (score 1):

After finding out that Yeoman is avoiding bad UX by excluding support for symlinks (see Simon Boudrias' comment), I knew I had to work around this issue. I did the following workaround, please note that this should only be applied if you're unable to avoid symlinks like I am.

```
var fs = require('fs');

// Find out if there are symlinks
var files = fs.readdirSync(this.destinationPath());
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {

  var path = this.destinationPath(files[i]),
      stats = fs.lstatSync(path);

  if (stats.isSymbolicLink()) {

    // Find the target of the symlink and make an identical link into the new location
    var link = fs.readlinkSync(path);
    fs.symlinkSync(link, this.destinationPath('build/html/' + files[i]));
  }
}
```